# When will Java's Runtime.maxMemory() return Long.MAX_VALUE?

Tags: java, memory

In the [documentation for Java's Runtime class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#maxMemory()) it states:

> Returns the maximum amount of memory that the Java virtual machine will attempt to use. If there is no inherent limit then the value Long.MAX_VALUE will be returned.

What does it mean by 'no inherent limit'? Won't there always be a max heap size?

Comment: I think you could read it as *no specified limit*, i.e. not at vm startup and there is no default value, it is probably vm-implementation and/or OS specific. Note that this method is declared  as `native`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All this means is that the specification does not require an explicit upper limit to exist. This had to be reflected in the API, otherwise the API of `maxMemory()` would have been inconsistent with the specification.